# network disabled

Tags: ethernet

I have just installed ubuntu server edition in order to create a home network. But I am not able to find IP of the machine through ifconfig (showing only localhost). Then I tried

```
 lspci | grep -i ethernet
```

output:

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
```

lshw -C Network

Then output was `*-network DISABLED`

Comment: Did you check your BIOS to see if its disabled?

Comment: how to check that. I do not have any "network" tab in BIOS menu.

Comment: What brand and Model system do you have?

Comment: My PC's motherboard is ASUS. And Bios is of AMI(american Megatrend inc)

Comment: What Model ASUS?

Comment: If you have a DHCP server running (like, on your router), just try setting it up temporarily: sudo ifconfig eth0 up; sudo dhclient etc.. sometimes it just needs a kick in the pants!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo less /var/log/installer/syslog

and check for eth0 or eth1 etc and see if it rejected your network card.

You didn't notice any problems during install though? It connected to the net and downloaded stuff alright?

If so, then try /var/log/dmesg

Comment: During installation the installer was not able to find dhcp server. So I skipped the network setting. Dose that causing the problem. And also its a server addition so it do not have gui and also its not able to recognize wired connection.

Comment: It might, I've never done that though. Did you check the logs?